# having an issue with mysql query to create views

Tags: mysql

Starting out with mysql and struggling with this issue, i would appreciate the help

I have an example table for software sales like this, the id is auto incremented and the entries are made as they are downloaded

```
 ID | App name   | platform | release date |downloadDate |price
====+============+==========+=============+==============+====== 
1   | calculator | windows  | 2013-03-01  | 2013-01-21   | $10 
2   | text editor| mac      | 2013-04-07  | 2013-02-24   | $8 
3   | mp3 player | mac      | 2013-01-23  | 2013-01-12   | $12 
4   | calendar   | linux    | 2012-08-15  | 2013-04-14   | $5 
5   | mp3 player | windows  |2013-02-11   | 2013-03-15   | $12 
6   | text editor| linux    |2012-10-13   | 2013-03-22   | $8 
7   | calculator | mac      |2013-04-24   | 2013-05-17   | $10 
8   | mp3 player | linux    |2013-04-16   | 2013-07-03   | $12 
9   | text editor| linux    |2013-03-22   | 2013-06-12   | $8 
10  | calendar   | mac      |2012-08-15   | 2013-04-14   | $5
```

what I'm trying to do is create 3 views to display the data

1. show the App name and the total for all platforms for that App and order then descending
   that x would be the total for all platform (win/mac/linux)

   ex.

   ```
   App name   | total
   ===========+======
   calculator | x
   mp3 player | x
   text editor| x
   ```
2. view show the App name and the total downloads for each platform and order then descending

   ex.

   ```
   App name   |platform |total
   ===========+=========+=====
   calculator | windows | 12
   calculator | mac     | 6
   calculator | linux   | 2
   ```
3. show the App name and the total for all platforms for that App and order then by price descending

   ex.

   ```
   App name   | total |price
   ===========+=======+====
   calculator | x     |$10
   mp3 player | x     |$12
   text editor| x     |$8
   ```

i have searched for an answer but could not find a very close case, it's a bit long winded post but it's as best as i can explain it?

Comment: What did you try? What went wrong?

Comment: You should read on database normalization, your downloads data should be in a different table than the app information (name,price,etc.)

Comment: thanks @koala_dev i looked into it and it's an important concept to know, but i thought it would not be a good idea here, this is my though process, but i welcome opinions, the db will track the sales, release date, user details, num of downloads and be used as download counter source, with more info going in than coming out, so i thought a 'main' db with everything and the views with only what was needed, say for ex to get num of downloads or monthly sales, the normalisation would mean those 'expensive' InnerJoins for everything including what was not needed every time, do i have this wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the views that you would probably need:

```
CREATE VIEW App AS
SELECT appname, COUNT(*) as Total FROM softwaresales
GROUP BY appname
ORDER BY Total DESC;

CREATE VIEW AppPlatform AS
SELECT appname, platform, COUNT(*) as Total FROM softwaresales
GROUP BY appname, platform
ORDER BY Total DESC;


CREATE VIEW AppPrice AS
SELECT appname, COUNT(*), price FROM softwaresales
GROUP BY appname
ORDER BY price DESC;
```

And you could call them like this:

```
SELECT * FROM App;
SELECT * FROM AppPlatform WHERE appname ='calculator';
SELECT * FROM AppPrice;
```

Check my [sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61b33)

Comment: Thanks @Edper, it was exactly what i was trying to do :)
As i said earlier on im just starting out with mysql, so if you would be patient with me and explain the code for me, i would appreciate, it's the GROUP BY part that i wasn't getting right, i think...

Comment: The GROUP BY is for aggregate functions like SUM, COUNT, AVG. For example we group it by AppName and let's say we are going to use the COUNT aggregate function. So, that means records in your table that has an app name as Calculator would be accumulated or counted to Calcuclator GROUP and so does all MP3 player would be accumulated or  counted into MP3 player group and so on.

Comment: @BobMachine see examples [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-group-by.htm)

Comment: thanks for the tip @Edper very helpful, that was the part i was missing